# How to print the Value.dereference() value in more decent format in GDB pretty-printer

Tags: python, gdb, pretty-print

In Python pretty-printers in GDB, Value.dereference() gives all the contents pointed to by object "Value". But the output is very cumbersome and it takes a while to read the output. Is there a better way to print the contents in more readable format?

Thanks.